# Crystal Report 2011 Missing Database Name without any reason, does not work on some pcs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I made a report using Crystal Report 2011, it works fine on most of the computers, but not all in such a way that Database name missed. Even i entered the name with Code, and also updated it correctly with its properties and configuration with server. It works fine on most of the pcs, but few pcs miss it, i reinstalled the crystal report runtime but it did not work.
I am attaching the error image.[image]

Comment: I am not using Integrated Security, it was just checked for testing but it does not work as well. This error is occurring without Integrated Security.

Answer (score 1):

call The Following Function After Load Report.

```
public void SetReportLogon(ReportDocument rptDoc)
    {
        if (rptConnection.ServerName == null || rptConnection.ServerName != DBHost)
            rptConnection.ServerName = DBHost;
        if (rptConnection.ServerName == null || rptConnection.DatabaseName != DBName)
            rptConnection.DatabaseName = DBName;

        rptConnection.UserID = DBUserID;
        rptConnection.Password = DBPassword;

        foreach (ReportDocument subRpt in rptDoc.Subreports)
        {
            foreach (Table crTable in subRpt.Database.Tables)
            {
                crTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = true;
                TableLogOnInfo logInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;                    
                logInfo.ConnectionInfo = rptConnection;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(logInfo);
            }
        }

        foreach (Table crTable in rptDoc.Database.Tables)
        {
            crTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.AllowCustomConnection = true;
            TableLogOnInfo loi = crTable.LogOnInfo;
            loi.ConnectionInfo = rptConnection;
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loi);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Call this Function After Load report

Answer (score 0):

Are you using integrated security or not? (the dialog box has both user/pass populated and integrated security ticked- which contradict eachother).

Please paste the code you are using to set the TableLogonInfo

Comment: I am not using Integrated Security, it was just checked for testing but it does not work as well. This error is occurring without Integrated Security.

Comment: I must be because the report is failing to login to the server/db- as it's not a user/pass problem it is likely to be a driver or network problem. How is your db connection defined? SQL native client? The drivers may need installing on these failing computers

Comment: Crystal Report uses Oledb connection.